# Open Source or Low Cost Layer 7 ("Content") Switch?

Tags: untagged

I have several web servers that host a number of different applications and web sites. I want to make it easy to host apps or parts of web sites on different servers (e.g. example.com/foo might be on one physical server and example.com/bar might be on another). We do this Apache redirects right now, but that gets messy fast and in any case we have other problems we want to solve, such as throttling requests from individual clients, and reducing dependency on specific physical hosts.

Is there an open source or low cost layer 7 switch that would be suitable for this sort of task? I was hoping to find something like a stripped down Linux VMware guest/appliance built for this purpose, but haven't seen anything suitable out there so far.

Answer (score 3):

[HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu) is an open source proxy that can do content switching.

Comment: We're using haproxy's content switching to try and migrate a php app over to rails. Here's a quick blog post about doing something like that. http://www.bwigg.com/2012/04/content-switching-with-haproxy/

Answer (score 3):

The [Squid-cache](http://www.squid-cache.org/) should be able to do this for you.

To quote from their web site:

> ...Squid's advanced content routing configuration allows you to build content clusters to route and load balance requests via a variety of web servers.

Configuration examples:

[Reverse Proxy with Domain Based Virtual Host Support](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/VirtualHosting)

[Reverse Proxy with Multiple Backend Web Servers](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/MultipleWebservers)

Answer (score 0):

[A Vyatta forum topic](http://www.vyatta.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2786&highlight=web+proxy) quickly degenerated into flame war (not really) a la lighttpd & nginx versus Squid versus Vyatta

Then a Vyatta employee used the term [*L7 server load balancing*](http://www.vyatta.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=1165#1165). . . .

Which finally led to [**Pound**](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/)!!!!!  (And on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_%28networking%29).)

BTW, Vyatta is the company/product whose name I couldn't remember, and whom I kept referring to as [Vinyasa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyasa).

Answer (score 0):

[nginx](http://nginx.org/).  [syntax for reverse proxy](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpProxyModule). and some examples of using it [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy) and [there](http://intranation.com/entries/2008/09/using-nginx-reverse-proxy/).